# How to center a Label in a scrollable Frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, scrollable

I am trying to create a label (for now and different widgets in the future) inside a scrollable tkinter Frame but it always shows in the upper left corner of the window. My code is shown below and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class ScrollableFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        
        self.scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: self.canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor=NW)

        self.canvas.pack(fill="both")
        
    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1*int(event.delta/120), "units")
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x150")
    
    frame = ScrollableFrame(root)

    for i in range(20):
        a = tk.Label(frame.scrollable_frame, text="Number: "+str(i))
        a.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)
        
    frame.pack(fill="both")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because the width of `self.scrollable_frame` is the max width of the labels inside it.  You can see the result by changing the background color of the canvas to other color.

Comment: Oh, thank you. the background color makes debugging so easy. the problem was the with of the canvas, its my 2nd time coding with UI and you gave me an excellent advice, thank you very much.